# Configure Raven using Celery and Django without Djcelery

Tags: django, celery, sentry, raven

How to configure django + raven with celery, without using the djcelery application that is in is out of date with celery 3.1+.

Old configuration using:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + (
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `djcelery` with Celery 3.1+, just add `raven.contrib.django.raven_compat` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
)

RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'YOUR_DSN',
}
```

There is a sample code of `LOGGING` setting:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s',
        },
        'clear': {
            'format': '%(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'clear',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true', ],
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false', ],
        },
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false', ],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'log_to_console': {
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'log_to_sentry': {
            'handlers': ['sentry', ],
            'level': 'WARNING',
        },
    },
}
```